# Fedora Linux - Switch command line to kde

Tags: linux, fedora, kde

I installed kde on my fedora 13 VM and now I want to switch to KDE . How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `/usr/bin/X` exists, if not do

```
yum install xorg-x11-server-Xorg
```

if its already installed, reinstall it by doing

```
yum reinstall xorg-x11-server-Xorg
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by command line terminal.  You can switch to kde by modifying or creating a file called `.xinitrc` in your home directory.  In that file, you will want to find any lines referring to your old window manager (probably `gnome-session`) and comment them.  Add `startkde` in your `.xinitrc`.  Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
xsetroot -solid black
startkde
```

You can also create a separate `.xinitrc` file to launch your X session independently:

```
xinit ~/.xinitrc.kde -- :1
```

This would launch your X session using a file called `.xinitrc.kde` and use display `:1`.  With this method, you could run 2 X sessions at the same time while testing.  To switch between them, use **Ctrl+Alt+F7** and **Ctrl+Alt+F8**.

This method will work in almost all linux distros.

Comment: you mean /home as the home directory? thanks for your help.

Comment: @teahupoo almost, he means "home directory" as the user's base directory, usually /home/user, or ~/ as a shorcut (if you are 'user')